# Merging isn't solving this. Line apparent in Object Mode

Tags: outliner

I've highlighted the lines. Tried merging the vertices, but no dice. Not sure how to make it like the bottom picture. The other side ended up pretty well.

[image]

Comment: Looks like its just edges that are separate from the model

Comment: Can you show a wire frame detail?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Vslir1F.png